# How to show 1 unit when mapping in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to loop through an array of Invitation from a team and a user can have many Invitation. So right now I want to when I clicked invite button, Invitation will be added into user object.

Here is how my project look like:
[image]

When I do `console.log(user)` to get all data from a user, the data looks like this:

```
InvitesApplications: Array(2)
0: {response: "Waiting on response", teamId: "4d45c102-0624-4467-ad11-5fa5eaadcf7e"}
1: {response: "Waiting on response", teamId: "5413e75f-ff12-4b7a-a3fe-f892cd006366"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
Memberships: []
Ratings: []
Skills: [{…}]
fullname: "nan"
public_user_id: "na1620384295502"
verifiedDT: "2021-05-07T07:30:19.947Z"
```

So I want to implement a way that when user have Invitation the invite button will be disappear, and if we search from another team that have teamId different with the `Invitations.teamId` and the button will appear. How can I do that?

Here is my following code for `Invitees.js`:

```
const Invitees = (props) => {
  const { tab, teamId, privateTeamId, fetchTeamData } = props;
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [invitees, setInvitees] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}/${teamId}`
    );
    setInvitees(res.data[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery === "") {
      setInvitees([]);
    }
  }, [searchQuery]);

  return (
    <div className="invitees-container">
      <div className="invitees-wrapper">
        <div className="invitees-sortes">
          Sort by: <u>Recommended</u>{" "}
          <svg
            width="12"
            height="6"
            viewBox="0 0 12 6"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path d="M6 6L0.803848 0L11.1962 0L6 6Z" fill="#A9A9A9" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="invitees-search">
            <Button
              className="input invitees--search-icon"
              style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#00B790" }}
              type="submit"
            >
              <SearchIcon />
            </Button>
            <input
              className="invitees--search_input"
              type="search"
              name="name"
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Name, Skill, Location"
              aria-label="Search bar"
              pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="stretch"
        spacing={7}
      >
        {invitees
          .filter(
            (userTeamId) =>
              userTeamId.Memberships.length < 1 ||
              userTeamId.Memberships.every(
                (member) => member.teamId !== privateTeamId
              )
          )
          .map((user, index) => (
            <Grid item key={index}>
              <div className="member-card">
                {user.InvitesApplications.map((ures, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    {ures.teamId === privateTeamId && (
                      <div>
                        {ures.response === "Waiting on response" && (
                          <div className="member-card-header pending">
                            Pending
                          </div>
                        )}
                        {ures.response === "Declined" && (
                          <div className="member-card-header declined">
                            Declined
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))}
                <div>
                  <InviteCard
                    tab={tab}
                    user={user}
                    teamId={teamId}
                    privateTeamId={privateTeamId}
                    onSubmitInvitee={handleSubmit}
                  />
                  {user.InvitesApplications.map((ures, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      {ures.response === "Declined" &&
                        ures.teamId === privateTeamId && (
                          <div className="declined-status">
                            Declined on{" "}
                            {moment(ures.updatedAt).format("MMMM DD, YYYY")}
                          </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
```

and here is my `InviteCard.js`:

```
const InviteCard = (props) => {
  const { user, tab, teamId, privateTeamId, onSubmitInvitee } = props;
  const [modalStatus, setModalStatus] = useState(false);
  const [limitType, setLimitType] = useState("team members");
  const appState = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const { setWhatToReload } = appState;

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalStatus(!modalStatus);
  };

  const notify = (message) =>
    toast.info(<CustomToastMessage message={message} />, {
      autoClose: 2000,
      closeButton: true,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      transition: Flip,
      position: "bottom-right",
    });

  async function inviteToTeam(e) {
    if (!user.verifiedDT) {
      notify("User has not verified their identity, can not invite.");
    } else {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/invites/invite", {
        userToInvite: user.public_user_id,
        teamId: teamId,
      });
      if (res.data.inviteWasCreated === false) {
        notify("User has already been invited.");
      } else if (res.data.error !== undefined) {
        notify(res.data.error);
      } else if (res.data.msg) {
        if (res.data.msg === "max members") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("team members");
        }
        if (res.data.msg === "max invites") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("invites");
        }
      } else {
        notify("Invite sent.");
        setWhatToReload("invite data");
        // onSubmitInvitee();
      }
    }
  }

  const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inviteToTeam();
  };
  console.log(user);

  return (
    <div className="invite-card-body">
      <div className="member-edit" onClick={openModal}>
        <Symlink />
      </div>
      {modalStatus && <TeamStatusModal active={modalStatus} tab={tab} />}
      <div
        className="member-avatar"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${user.picture})`,
        }}
      />
      <div className="member-description">
        <p className="member-name">{user.fullname}</p>
        <p className="member-position">{user.major}</p>
      </div>
      {/* {user.InvitesApplications.length > 1 && } */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitInvite}>
        <button type="submit" className="invitees-invite-button">
          Invite
        </button>
      </form>
      {user.InvitesApplications.length < 1 && (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmitInvite(e)}>
          <button type="submit" className="invitees-invite-button">
            Invite
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Added codesandbox exaample: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hugle-4m835?file=/src/App.js

Comment: *" and if we search from another team that have teamId different with the Invitations.teamId and the button will appear"* - I don't understand this part. Is there different types of searches? Could you make a codesandbox?

Comment: @TJ sorry for late reply, I will make a codesandbox right now

Comment: @TJ https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hugle-4m835?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can anyone help me in this codesandbox ?

Comment: This appears to be working. Could you explain more about what the issue is? It's unclear. https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-meadow-eq1f7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I just adjusted some code and it worked But I am having a problem about ther handle Submit. As you can see in my question at `Invite.js` file I have a handle submit and I passed it to `InviteCard.js` to callback when I hit invite button in InviteCard but I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefine`

Comment: @ZacharyHaber how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it appears that the original ask has been resolved. The other issue being asked is about why there's an issue with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

In `InviteCard.js`, you need to make sure to pass the event through all the way. Or in your `Invitees.js` `handleSubmit` code, check to see if event is defined before calling preventDefault (which you can do using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `event?.preventDefault()`)

```
  async function inviteToTeam(e) {
    if (!user.verifiedDT) {
      notify("User has not verified their identity, can not invite.");
    } else {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/invites/invite", {
        userToInvite: user.public_user_id,
        teamId: teamId,
      });
      if (res.data.inviteWasCreated === false) {
        notify("User has already been invited.");
      } else if (res.data.error !== undefined) {
        notify(res.data.error);
      } else if (res.data.msg) {
        if (res.data.msg === "max members") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("team members");
        }
        if (res.data.msg === "max invites") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("invites");
        }
      } else {
        notify("Invite sent.");
        setWhatToReload("invite data");
        onSubmitInvitee(e); // Pass event into `onSubmitInvitee`
      }
    }
  }

  const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inviteToTeam(e); // Pass event through to `inviteToTeam`
  };
```